# How do you manage your pages or functions that require logged-in users?

Tags: users, login, user-access, authentication

I'm having more functions and pages that require my users to be logged-in.

Below is what I have in each of my functions, kind of a hassle to keep repeating this code.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

//If user is not logged in...
if ( $user_id == 0 ) {
    nocache_headers();
    wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); 
    exit();
}
```

And for pages, I use [Content Control](https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-control/) plugin.

I wonder how you manage yours and perhaps you can offer a more simplified solution to ensure the user is logged in while accessing.

UPDATE: I use the above instead of `is_user_logged_in()` cos most times I need to access $user_id.

Comment: For starters there's the `is_user_logged_in()` function, but there's not enough context here to know what else you might want to do.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I was thinking maybe some could host the repetitive code on say a header or external file that can be easily referred to. I just wanna know how others are doing this?

Comment: You could include it all in a function, but your question is very vague so it’s not clear what’s repetitive about your code and what issue you’re trying to solve. Where are you currently putting the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use `template_redirect` action to check, if a user has access to certain content, e.g. a page. To me, it is the most logical and straightforward place to handle the checking. As per the docs, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/, the action,

> Fires before determining which template to load.

Also the WP object has been already set up and the current user is known, so checking the user and the content is easy.

To mark something as restricted content, I might use a page template, a custom taxonomy, or just plain post meta - depending on the use case and how lazy I'm feeling at that moment.

I might do something like this,

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_maybe_protected_content' );
function my_maybe_protected_content() : void {
  
  // optional conditions..
  if ( ! is_page() ) {
    return;
  }
  
  // current post id
  // use get_queried_object(), if post object is needed
  $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
  
  // check for protected content
  if ( ! my_is_protected_content($post_id) ) {
    return;
  }
  
  // access and/or auth chcecks
  if ( 
    ! is_user_logged_in() || 
    ! my_user_has_access(
      wp_get_current_user(), $post_id
    )
  ) {
    my_redirect_user();
  }
}

function my_is_protected_content(int $post_id) : bool {
  
  // option 1 - determine from template
  if ( 'path/to/page-template.php' === get_page_template_slug( $post_id ) ) {
    return true;
  }
  
  // option 2 - use a custom taxonomy
  if ( has_term( 'is_protected_content', 'my_utility_taxonomy', $post_id ) ) {
    return true;
  }
  
  // option 3 - check from post meta
  $protected_by_meta_flag = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_protected_content_meta_key', true );
  if ( $protected_by_meta_flag ) {
    return true;
  }
  
  // default...
  return false;
  
}

function my_user_has_access(WP_User $user, int $post_id) : bool {
  // some fancy logic...
  return true;
}

function my_redirect_user() {
  nocache_headers();
  wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); 
  exit();
}
```

The code would go into `functions.php`, an additional PHP file required in `functions.php`, or a custom plugin.